# Wait cursor for javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a .jsp page that users can enter information and then save it with a save button.  The application works, but because the click event of the button is running Java code, which then adds the saved information to an Oracle db, it takes a few moments before the save is complete.

I need a way to show the users a wait cursor so they will know when the save is complete.  However, I can't figure out how the .jsp page will know when the Java code has completed.

Here is a snippet:

```
    function updateTrans() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    if (validateTrans()) {
      if(editform.cbFg.checked) {
        editform.Fg.value = "Y";
      }
      else {
        editform.Fg.value = "N";
      }
      editform.myaction.value = "updateTrans";
      editform.submit();
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
  }
```

This does not work.  I guess the `editform.submit();` happens asynchronously.

Please help.

EDIT:  The target of `editform` is a servlet.
EDIT:  The servlet is a java page(HttpServlet), not a web page.

Comment: Does you `editform` have a target? A hidden iframe or something?

Comment: Yes, it has a target that is a servlet

Comment: okay I updated my answer. I hope it's clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the servlet that the form submits to is on the same domain as the parent page, you can output javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.document.body.style.cursor = 'default';`
</script>
```

from your servlet, to switch the cursor back to default when the servlet responds.

Then you can just remove the line:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
```

From your current script, since you'll let the servlet handle changing the cursor back.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the submit of the form will perform the default of browser and your page will be refreshed, correct?

If you use one ajax call instead of submiting the page you can control the flow.